# Retrieve "row pairs" from Excel

Tags: c#, linq, excel, grouping

I am trying to retrieve data from an Excel spreadsheet using C#. The data in the spreadsheet has the following characteristics:

- no column names are assigned
- the rows can have varying column lengths
- some rows are metadata, and these rows label the content of the columns in the next row

Therefore, the objects I need to construct will always have their name in the very first column, and its parameters are contained in the next columns. It is important that the parameter names are retrieved from the row above. An example:

```
row1|---------|FirstName|Surname|

row2|---Person|Bob------|Bloggs-|

row3|---------|---------|-------|

row4|---------|Make-----|Model--|

row5|------Car|Toyota---|Prius--|
```

So unfortunately the data is heterogeneous, and the only way to determine what rows "belong together" is to check whether the first column in the row is empty. If it is, then read all data in the row, and check which parameter names apply by checking the row above.
At first I thought the straightforward approach would be to simply loop through

1) the dataset containing all sheets, then 
2) the datatables (i.e. sheets) and 
3) the row.

However, I found that trying to extract this data with nested loops and if statements results in horrible, unreadable and inflexible code.
Is there a way to do this in LINQ ? I had a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396954/how-to-filter-out-null-rows-from-datatable-with-linq) to start by filtering the empty rows between data but didn't really get anywhere. Could someone point me in the right direction with a few code snippets please ?

Thanks in advance !
hiro

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that LINQ is not good choice for that kind of problems. Even if you'll get it done using LINQ it will be unreadable and inflexible, and that's because of the data you're trying to read, not because of method chosen to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you've already accepted the answer, but I think that more generic solution is possible - using reflection.

Let say you got your data as a `List<string[]>` where each element in the list is an array of string with all cells from corresponding row.

```
List<string[]> data;
data = LoadData();

var results = new List<object>();
string[] headerRow;

var en = data.GetEnumerator();
while(en.MoveNext())
{
    var row = en.Current;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[0]))
    {
        headerRow = row.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        Type objType = Type.GetType(row[0]);
        object newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);

        for(int i = 0; i < headerRow.Length; i++)
        {
            objType.GetProperty(headerRow[i]).SetValue(newItem, row[i+1]);
        }
        results.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant ! This is as close to a solution as I can expect. Willem hope it's ok if mark this as a solution, but your input is equally appreciated of course =)

Comment: Nice! I like the reflection... +1

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I'm not at all familiar with C#, but the idea is elegant. Is that possible for VBA - could you provide a link or sample? And of course this is a fair upvote.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience with VBA.